# Flowtype: Specify that array of functions can not be empty

Tags: flowtype

I have the following code:

```
function injectSagas (sagas: Array<Function>) {
  sagas.map(store.runSaga)
}
```

Can I somehow make flow trow an error if `sagas` array is empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `sagas` a tuple:

```
function injectSagas (sagas: [Function]) {
  sagas.map(() => {})
}
```

It guarantees that `sagas` has at least one element.

Comment: Annotating `sagas` as a tuple of one element wouldn't allow to pass array with multiple functions. That annotation results in following error when called on array of two elements: _Tuple arity mismatch. This tuple has 2 elements and cannot flow to the 1 elements of tuple type_.

Comment: Exactly. I finished with `sagas: Array<Function>`, because I realized in some cases it can be empty.

Answer (score -1):

You can use union type :

```
function injectSagas (sagas: [Function] | Array<Function>) {
    sagas.map(() => {})
}
```

Comment: In this case our array can be empty, because `Array<Function>` allows empty arrays.